# How to migrate production environment from EC2-Classic to VPC?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, load-balance

I need to migrate production environment from EC2-Classic to VPC. For now I have one Elastic LB with a few EC2 instances behind it.
My plan is:

1. create a new LB balancer and add VPC instance
2. create 2 Route53 records using Weighted Round Robin (http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/05/24/amazon-route53-elb-integration-wrr-ga/), which will point, for instance 90% traffic to the old LB and 10% to new
3. if everything going well, we can add  more  instances  to VPC  and change Route53 weights
4. at the end we'll leave just one DNS record and shutdown old LB

Will it work? Is there better method?

TIA,
Vitaly

Comment: why not just setup the new load balancer, then test it before you touch dns, and if it works cut DNS over all at once?

Comment: because we'd like to "test" our new VPC servers under production load for while before final switchover.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that should work (and is the way you should do it in the cloud).
Just copy the whole infrastructure and then shift over the traffic to the new one and control the metrics of both infrastructures.